# CIL OpCode (Ldarg_0) is used even though there are no arguments

Tags: c#, clr, cil, il

I have the following C# code.

```
public void HelloWorld()
{
    Add(2, 2);
}

public void Add(int a, int b)
{
    //Do something
}
```

It produces the following CIL

```
.method public hidebysig instance void  HelloWorld() cil managed
{
  // Code size       11 (0xb)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldarg.0
  IL_0002:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_0003:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_0004:  call       instance void ConsoleApplication3.Program::Add(int32,
                                                                      int32)
  IL_0009:  nop
  IL_000a:  ret
} // end of method Program::HelloWorld
```

Now, what I don't understand is the line at offset 0001:

> `ldarg.0`

I know what that opcode is for, but I don't really understand why it's being used in this method, as there are no arguments, right?

Does someone know why? :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I have to do ldarg.0 before calling a field in MSIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785372/why-do-i-have-to-do-ldarg-0-before-calling-a-field-in-msil)

Comment: @Pharap this question has already received plenty of good answers, but thanks :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think that the `ldarg.0` is loading `this` onto the stack. See this answer 
[MSIL Question (Basic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473346/msil-question-basic?rq=1)

Answer (score 23):

In instance methods there is an implicit argument with index 0, representing the instance on which the method is invoked. It can be loaded on the IL evaluation stack using `ldarg.0` opcode.

Answer (score 2):

The line at offset 0001: Loads the argument at index 0 onto the evaluation stack.

See more in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldarg_0.aspx

> The argument at index 0 is the `instance` of the `class` that contains
>   the methods `HelloWorld` and `Add`,  as this (or self in other
>   languajes)

```
 IL_0001:  ldarg.0   //Loads the argument at index 0 onto the evaluation stack.

 IL_0002:  ldc.i4.2  //Pushes a value 2 of type int32 onto the evaluation stack.

 IL_0003:  ldc.i4.2  //Pushes a value 2 of type int32 onto the evaluation stack.

 IL_0004:  call instance void ConsoleApplication3.Program::Add(int32, int32)
```

...this last line is as call: `this.Add(2,2);` in C#.